# Error shown in json

Tags: javascript, json

I am a beginner in javascript and i am building a json code for a website.The problem is that error messages are shown for style but i have used style in the code.Error message is:`
1:Bad template.json: Expecting property name: line 24 column 2 (char 530)
2:we encountered the following error at the top level of template.json (property style is missing.)

The name is json file is template.json and i have used two images also.No variable is used but i have created a space for future use.

```
{
    "id": "first-123",
    "name": "Get Paid",
    "mobile": true,
    "notes": "Initial import; first pass.",
    "syntax": 4,
    "version": 1.00,
    "style": 
    {
         "replacements": 
         [
             {
                "type": "color",
                "name": "Background Color",
                "find": "#FFFFFE"
              }
         ]
     },
    "elements":
         [
              {
                 "type": "image-link",
                 "id": "img/34769901.jpg",
                 "name": "Example 7 Image Link",
                       "data": 
                          {
                              "max-width": 1340
                          },

              {
                 "type": "image-link",
                 "id": "img/34769901.jpg",
                 "name": "Example 7 Image Link",
                 "data": 
                          {
                               "max-width": 1340
                          },


               }
          ],
    "variables": {}
}
```

Comment: http://jslint.com/ will be able to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma after last element in array/hash

```
   "max-width": 1340
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

yo are also missing a closing bracket, change

```
"elements":
     [
          {
             "type": "image-link",
             "id": "img/34769901.jpg",
             "name": "Example 7 Image Link",
                   "data": 
                      {
                          "max-width": 1340
                      },

          {
             "type": "image-link",
             "id": "img/34769901.jpg",
             "name": "Example 7 Image Link",
             "data": 
                      {
                           "max-width": 1340
                      },


           }
      ],
```

to

```
"elements":
     [
          {
             "type": "image-link",
             "id": "img/34769901.jpg",
             "name": "Example 7 Image Link",
                   "data": 
                      {
                          "max-width": 1340
                      }
          },

          {
             "type": "image-link",
             "id": "img/34769901.jpg",
             "name": "Example 7 Image Link",
             "data": 
                      {
                           "max-width": 1340
                      }


           }
      ],
```

Comment: where should we write <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lpc-show-rev-1408448475.js"></script> in an html code..when i write in the end,it shows script not used.please help